# django md5 auth ajax

Tags: django-authentication

I want to send javascript encrypted password to server URL (/account/login) and get an auth status that way:

```
var headers = {"X-CSRFToken": geo.helpers.readCookie('csrftoken')};
yajax.send({
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/account/login/",
    "data": {"login": "foo", "password": md5('533')},
    "header": headers,
    "success": function(response) { alert(response) }
})
```

Is there a way to authenticate not a plain password using standard mechanisms ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather not. You propably have to implement your own login method based on django User model.

Comment: contrib/auth/hashers.py changed